# How do I deploy an SSRS solution?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, wix

This is an extremely vague question because I don't know enough to know what I don't know.  Here's my situation:

I have downloaded SSDT and connected to a data source (A SQL Server DB instance).  I've created a report.  I can preview the report in VS.  I can publish the report from the VS build menu and it gets published to my local reports server that seems to have been installed by default at http://localhost/reports.  I can use a browser to go to that url and see the report I created.

Now, the problem is that this is all only in my local development environment.  I installed SSDT through Visual Studio and it auto-created my reports server.  Is there a way to install a reports server without installing visual studio and publish the reports from a report solution using an MSI created by a packager like WiX?  I'm having a hard time finding information about how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report server is typically installed when you install SQL Server. If you want to publish reports so that others can use them do the following:

1. Go to your VS solution and right-click on the project then select properties.
2. Set the TargetReportFolder (this will be created if it does not
   exist). This will usually reflect the name of the group of reports
   you are working on (e.g. 'HR Reports')
3. Set the  TargetServerURL to the report server on your SQL Server box for example http://mySQLServerBox/reportserver/
4. Set the TargetServerVersion to match your SQL Server installation version (SQL Server 2016 etc)
5. Now you can simply right-click a report rdl in VS and choose deploy, you can also do the same at the folder level to deploy all the reports in one go.

To access the reports, go to the web portal which will usually be http://MySQLServerBox/reports

I hope this is what you are looking for..

Comment: This works locally, but what about if I need to distribute the reports to multiple groups?  For example, we have a development lab environment and we have a separate QA lab environment and the reports server is different in both.  I would like to be able to click the installer, have it ask the URL for the reports server and then publish to that server.  I can't statically set it in VS before checking in.  It has to be dynamic during installation.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. Other may have more knowledge though, it's just not something I've ever tried before.

Comment: Our QA team, and also our customers, don't have VS installed.  Is there really no way to deploy reports without VS?

Comment: Maybe, I just have never tried. Changing the server URL only takes a few seconds though so as long as you have access to both server you could deploy to both pretty quickly.

Comment: That's true.  But it's more an issue of people who don't have VS needing to install.  I definitely won't have access to a client's DB, so I need to be able to give them an install kit with instructions that doesn't require a VS license and install.

Comment: OK I see now. I didn't realise these were for clients. The only other thing I can think of is either using ReportBuilder to deploy (as it's free) or give clients instructions on deploying the reports directly via the web interface (there's an option up upload RDL's in the web portal). Neither of these is ideal but could suffice for a small number of reports. Report Builder is probably the easiest for the client as it's not SQL Server Version dependant, uploading via web portal can differ from version to version.

Comment: Look at this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johndesch/2012/12/17/using-the-rs-exe-utility-to-deploy-a-report-server-project-and-shared-dataset/

Comment: Looks like this was, in fact, the solution.  I wanted to avoid vb scripting, so I ended up writing a custom C# app, but it does basically the same thing as the script there.